# Remote Wake On USB

Tags: networking, windows-10, usb, ethernet, sleep

I would like to be able to remotely wake up my Windows 10 laptop that does not have an Ethernet port and found out my laptop has an wake-on USB function (I'm not able to remotely wake my laptop up using an Ethernet to USB adapter, which I mentioned in an earlier post). I'm able to wake my laptop up from sleep mode by clicking the button of a USB mouse connected to it.

Is there a way I can remotely send a signal to the USB port on my laptop to wake my laptop up? I was looking into power over ethernet splitters and Ethernet port hubs with power delivery but am not too familiar with those concepts and if they could work.

Comment: [create a scheduled task](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson2/)

Comment: You don't need PoE, you need a WoL-capable USB-Ethernet adapter and BIOS support for that - it may likely not exist.